# Payload handling outside the scope of the on_message callback

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm developing a code using the following technologies: Python, Mqtt, Mosquitto, Paho and Docker

The code works perfectly, I can connect to my pseudo broker (Mosquitto that is in Docker), send and receive my payloads. What bothers me and what I'm trying to do is to treat the payload received outside the paho callback, because the standard way of using it is:

```
# Function for the on_message callback
def receive_payload(client: mqtt.Client, userdata: dict[str, Any], message: mqtt.MQTTMessage) -> None:
     pass

# callback on_message
client: mqtt.Client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_message = receive_payload
```

I want to deal with it outside the scope of the on_message callback, as I wanted to add a return and use it in other parts and modules in my code. How can I do this without using global variables? I've searched on google and chatgpn and haven't found a definitive solution

Comment: What information are you trying to use?  You have the client in a global, but it's quite likely that the message payload ceases to exist shortly after your handler returns.  You might have to copy the payload to a global (or create a class and use a member variable, which is a more acceptable way of doing a global).

Comment: Yes, I do my client in a "global" way through object-oriented programming, I needed to "export" this payload for manipulation and reuse outside the callback

Comment: OK, but what is going to trigger that "manipulation and reuse"?  How will you know that something new has been received?  What happens if you receive several messages right in a row?  This is a real-time process, and you need to think about the signalling and data flow.

Comment: In this case, I'm thinking of working with a list-type global variable:

```
payloads_read: list[dict[str, Any]] = [] # It will already have passed through a function and will enter dict format in the list
```
and make a function to read these payloads every [X] ms (ex: 2000ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your way of thinking.

MQTT messages are delivered asynchronously, the `on_message` callback is only run when a message is delivered from the broker which matches a topic pattern the client is subscribed to. That means there is no where to "return" to, because there is nowhere in your code you could call a function that would ever return something. At the point you make the "call" there could have never been a message delivered or many, which do you want?

What you want to do is to have the `on_message` function trigger what ever processing you want to do with the value.

If you have a loop running that will change behaviour based on a value then you can use the `on_message` function to store it in a global variable.

```
payload = None

def on_message (client, userdata, message):
   global payload
   payload = message.payload
   ...

client.on_message = on_message
```

Comment: Okay, I'll proceed with the global variable form, thanks!